# CSS not showing up when opening with files

Tags: css, sass

My css only works when I open it with live-server. I didn't realized it until I tried opening the file
of my projects. The JS functionality is there, but my project is just stale, just black and white. I'm using sass and live-sass compiler. And also using a map api leaftlet and open weather api. SO please help,
cannot seems to figure out why my css is not present when I open my project on file or in another browser.

Comment: Could you please give more details about your directory structure, how you import your CSS file?

Comment: i have a index.html, app.js and a sass folder which contains my main.scss which complies it into regular css using live sass compiler. And my style.css is link as usual.

Comment: I can't help you with this little detail. It's so ambiguous.

Comment: hey Nguyen, thanks so much for the help. Can you please check my github. https://github.com/rabtennamgyal/Basic-Project-/tree/main/Basic%20Begineer%20Projects/weather%20data%20project  I do not use any bundler or anything. I have a file, which contains my index.html, app.js and my sass folder, that's all. PLease check my github where this file is located, please HELP.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen through your file and I think your issue is your image hasn't been loaded.

You have an image of the starry sky, right? You can only see the black and white page with some icons after the search because your image hasn't been loaded.

As you access the page by opening the file, the image URL in your CSS file is the path relatives to the current CSS file, which means the URL should be `../image/night.jpg`.

If you access the page through the live server, that URL is the path relative to your host.

Hope that I understand your problem correctly. I am still learning too :)

[image]

Comment: thanks so much, I really appreciate it. But no, that wasn't the problem.                                                 https://postimg.cc/N97R8CHc my project appears like this, the navbar is way to big and all the styles are messed up. But js and the weather api im using still works. But thanks for your help.

Comment: @TheMonkeyKing Your CSS file is loaded so the big navbar and the styles are your CSS or JS code problem (I haven't check it yet). But the white background is caused by the wrong URL. Try to change it.

Comment: how exactly do i change my url. when i use live-server it works but not when opening with file.

Comment: @TheMonkeyKing As I explain above, when you use live-server, the image URL is relative with the host, but when you open the file, the image URL must be relative with the file.
In the image I uploaded, you see that the background image's URL is now having `..` before the first `/` in order to make it relative with the image file.

Comment: Man I finally got it. Thanks so much, it was the img but the main problem was with the sass/css link in the html. And for whatever reason when I use rem the sizes were ok but when I open with file, the sizes are way to big... so had to change that too. Anyway, thanks a bunch. 